# EF Core - Query with many to many relationship very slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to do a "simple" query with Entity Framework Core that involves a many to many relationship.

Currently the execution time of the query is very slow because most of it seems to be run locally. I get the following warnings in my logs:

```
 The LINQ expression 'where ([categoryId] == [categoryRelationEntity].CategoryId)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
 The LINQ expression 'Any()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
 ...
```

The warnings basically tell me that nothing could be done in SQL and everything was done locally.

Here is my query in LINQ:

```
var categoryIds = new int[] { 1 , 2 , 3 };
var result = await _dbSet // MyTable
                    .Include(x => x.Categories) // CategoriesRelation
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.CategoryEntity)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(x=>  x.Categories
                        .All(categoryRelationEntity => categoryIds.Any(categoryId => categoryId == categoryRelationEntity.CategoryId)))
                    .ToListAsync();
```

If I write the SQL myself it should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN CategoriesRelation ON MyTable.Id = CategoriesRelation.MyTableId
WHERE "CategoryId" IN (1,2,3)
```

Is something wrong with how I wrote my LINQ? I did some research and all resources that I found suggested I had to do All() and Any().

I tried many different things and nothing worked... I'm so frustrated that I'm very close to just writing it in raw sql...

Comment: your tables are not clear. your linq doesn't have MyTable. Your SQL doesn't have Category and CategoryEntity. Can post table structures to make it clear for us? The "Include", "Where" and "ToList" will cause slower performance. Use AsQueryable() instead of ToList().

Comment: your problem is definitely within the Where statement. I don't undersand your query. MAny to many in ef core is usually done with a join table inbetween. What are you doing in that Where() method?

Comment: @Asherguru the "_dbSet" is "MyTable" and the .Include(x => x.Categories) is the "CategoriesRelation".

Comment: @JohanHerstad The "Categories" is the join table that is inbetween. The name is a little bit confusing in the code. I added two comments maybe it makes it a bit clearer which property is which table. The where clause should select all MyTable entities where all categories of that entity are in the given category id array. It does the same as the SQL query but much slower.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `categoryIds.Contains(categoryId)` method instead `.Any()`

Comment: Definitely the right answer. I'm using this in a lot of code. Just to make it more obvious, it's something like "... .Where(x => categoryIds.Contains(x.categoryId)) ..."

Answer (score 0):

Download Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore from nuget. ToListAsync() causes slower performance. Use AsQueryableAsync() instead for better performance. And use code below

```
var result = await _dbSet
                   .IncludeFilter(x => x.Categories.Where(x => categoryIds.Contains(x.categoryId)))
                   .ThenInclude(x => x.CategoryEntity).AsQueryableAsync();
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't suggest installing another dependency for getting a simple "... WHERE IN ..." running.

Comment: Without dependency, need to use 2-3 code lines to get that query as the filter cannot work in regular "Include" linq. This one is just 1 code line.

Comment: It does work. I guess you are talking about query performance for includes since they aren't filtered in the first place (all data is joined (EF Core >3.0) and queried and filtered by .Where at the end of the linq query) When this is a problem you are right in that EF Plus is really helpful with its IncludeFilter() method. But this is a completely other question.

Comment: He wants to improve linq performance. I edited my answer for performance screenshot. You can compare performance between includefilter and regular one. Both have same data list. But includefilter lessens the code and faster performance.

Comment: As in my comment before, I never doubted the performance boost by using IncludeFilter(). But you're right, question can be read as a performance related one rather than a 'not-working'-one. Sorry, I missed that yesterday. So I removed my downgrade and voted up. Besides, this conversation might certainly add value to the questioner.